# Please help me understand how to differentiate with logarithm?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

> $$\dfrac{\partial\ln E(p_x,p_y,V)}{\partial\ln p_x}=\dfrac1{E(p_x,p_y,V)}\cdot\frac{\partial E(p_x,p_y,V)}{\partial p_x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial p_x}{\partial\ln p_x}$$

How did we get this differentiation?I can't handle $\partial\ln p_x$ in denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
$$
and the differentiation of inverse
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{1}{\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}}. 
$$
so that for $y=\ln E, x=\ln p_x, z=p_x$
$$
\dfrac{\partial\ln E}{\partial\ln p_x}=\frac{\partial \ln E}{\partial p_x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial p_x}{\partial\ln p_x}=\dfrac1{E}\cdot\frac{\partial E}{\partial p_x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial p_x}{\partial\ln p_x}=\dfrac1{E}\cdot\frac{\partial E}{\partial p_x}\cdot p_x
$$
This is, by definition, the [elasticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_a_function) of $E$ with respect to $p_x$.

Comment: Thank you soooo much Sir, I expected mathematical answer only, but got the economic intuitions too!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\partial \log E(p_x,p_y,V)}{\partial \log p_x}\cdot\frac{\partial \log p_x}{\partial p_x}=\frac{\partial \log E(p_x,p_y,V)}{\partial p_x}$$

Comment: Thank you so much,Sir. I wanted to comment this yesterday ASAP, but the site showed that your answer has been deleted! Then I slept.