# Where am I wrong applying chain rule here?

Tags: calculus, self-learning, partial-derivative

Why is $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(tx_1, \dots, tx_n)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial(tx_i)}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{\partial(tx_i)}{\partial x_i}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{\partial(tx_i)}{\partial x_i}$$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/620391/94817) ? I think it is NOT equal as, I have [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/607814/94817) answer, and according to it, I should go this way: $$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial(tx_i)}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{\partial(tx_i)}{\partial x_i}&=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial(tx_i)}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_i}\cdot\dfrac{\partial(tx_i)}{\partial x_i}\\&=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial(tx_i)}\cdot\dfrac{\partial(tx_i)}{\partial x_i}\\&=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{t}{t}\\&=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\\& \neq\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{\partial(tx_i)}{\partial x_i}\end{align}$$

Please help! I am stuck in my Microeconomics course.

Comment: How did you get $\frac{t}{t}$ in the second line?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial(tx_i)}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)\cdot\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_i}=\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial (tx_i)}\cdot\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)=\dfrac1t\cdot \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)$$ as per [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607779/please-help-me-understand-how-to-differentiate-with-logarithm/607814#607814) answer. I am also editing this in the question.

Comment: Isn't $$\;\frac{\partial (tx_i)}{\partial x_i}=t\;\ldots?$$

Comment: @DonAntonio, pardon, but I can't understand what are $\dots$ for?

Comment: Decoration, @Sush ...

Comment: Oh, nice, now I have edited my previous comment, How to solve the question in itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with partial derivatives, but instead it is confusion about the chain rule.

Consider $f(g(x))$. We have $$\frac{d}{dx}[f(g(x))] = \frac{df}{dx}(g(x))\frac{dg}{dx}(x) = \frac{d}{dg}[f(g(x))]\frac{dg}{dx}(x).$$

The key part is that $$\frac{df}{dx}(g(x)) = \frac{d}{dg}[f(g(x))].$$

In your situation $$\frac{df}{dx}(tx) = \frac{d}{d(tx)}[f(tx)].$$

Sorry if I have led you astray with some of my previous comments.

Comment: But, again, $ \frac{d}{d(tx)}[f(tx)]=\frac{d}{d(tx)}[f(tx)]\cdot  \frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}[f(tx)]\cdot\frac{dx}{d(tx)}=\frac{d}{dx}[f(tx)]\cdot \frac{1}{t}\neq\frac{df}{dx}(tx) $, isn't it?

Comment: How did you get from $\frac{d}{d(tx)}[f(tx)]\cdot\frac{dx}{dx}$ to $\frac{d}{dx}[f(tx)]\cdot\frac{dx}{d(tx)}$?